# Build clustering upon matrix lines with Kmeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

**BIG EDIT**

The original code was:

The the plotting of a graph that corresponds to the reading of a text file with n lines. Each line contains 4 columns,the first three columns are coordinates of (x,y,z) points, and the fourth column is a binary variable not necessary for this plotting. At each 20 lines read, a skeleton is read, this skeleton being a group of 20 (x,y,z) points or joints, each joint made by the first three columns of each line.

Example of a text file content: A text file contains 860 lines, and 860/20 = 43, being 20 the number of joints to create a skeleton of (x,y,z) joints. Then, the text file is made of 43 skeletons, that generates a movement. Therefore, the text file represents a **movement**. I've called it "example" because the numbers vary.

After building the code to read the skeleton's movements, I've made a big 2D array that contains all the movements together, and the result was a 22797x400 array, where each line is a skeleton. Therefore, there are 22797 skeletons, with 400 columns for each. I've called this last 2D array of **final_array**.

I've applied the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) to **final_array**, where I've used the V matrix from SVD (that results in S, V and D matrices) to make a multiplication between final_array and a reduced version of V (which is originally 400x400), resulting in a 22797x3 2D array, since the reduced version of V was 400x3. This was necessary for some reasons that don't need to be mentioned here, but it was for dimension reduction to plot the skeletons in upcoming parts of the process.

Hence, I have a 22797x3 2D array, where each line represents a skeleton, built from operations explained above, and I need to apply clustering to this matrix, where each line will be clustered to a group, using Kmeans from Scikit-learn in Python. It must be a cluster with 100 clustering groups.

What I need to have as  result is the kmeans_labels result, with a list of 22797 elements, informing was group of the 100 clustering groups each line (skeleton) was grouped at.

So far I've tried:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=100, random_state=0).fit(matrix)
```

But the result was the following error message:

**Number of distinct clusters (68) found smaller than n_clusters (100). Possibly due to duplicate points in X.
  return_n_iter=True)**

It doesn't matter how many times I change the groups number, the error message returns with a smaller value.
Any hep?

Comment: Are there duplicate rows?

Comment: Yes, because each vector represents a sequence of movements of a skeleton, so certain movements repeat.

Comment: There's a huge lack of information in this question that's causing some confusion, so I've updated the whole question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your data matrix is mostly composed of repeated vectors.
So from your 22797 data points, there are only 68 different vectors and the rest are just repetitions of these 68 values.
Try printing the matrix. I believe you either you are not reading the data as you should, or you are not measuring them the right way

Comment: In fact it should be like that, because each vector represents a sequence of  movements of a skeleton, so certain movements repeat. What I need to do is create a clustering to group those movements and know what's the occurence rate of each of the 68 vectors. So, is K-means the appropriate method? I've no previous experience with the subject.

Comment: I see, so it is kind of a time series. Are all your sequence of movements of the same length? what is their length?

Comment: Yes, they're 3 columns long. Each line being a movement contains 3 columns. The original dimention of each line is 400, but I've reduced it to 3, to make it easier to build the clustering.

Comment: I forgot to mention that each line is a whole movement, not just a "frame". Each movement was 400 columns long (400 frames long), but as I've said previously, I reduced the dimension to 3 (frames) to make it easier.

Comment: so just to be clear. you have 7599 sequences, each of them is composed of 3 frames,   so 7599*3 = 22797.  And each frame is encoded with 3 values

Comment: There's a huge lack of information in this question that's causing some confusion, so I've updated the whole question to make it clearer.